# Angular.js directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to pass in a variable from a controller to a directives attribute value. I am using this directive https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer. And my code looks like this

```
  <div ng-controller="transactionsController">
              <table class="table" data-row-style="rowStyle">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Link to Transaction</th>
                  <th>Amount Invested</th>
                  <th>Payout Amount</th>
                  <th>Transaction Status</th>
                  <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="transaction in transactions">
                  <td><a href='https://blockchain.info/tx/{{transaction.input_transaction_hash}}'> {{transaction.input_transaction_hash}} </a></td>
                  <td> {{transaction.value/100000000}} </td>
                  <td> {{(transaction.value/100000000) * 1.2}} </td>  <!--TODO: Investment % shouldn't be hardcoded -->
                  <td class='red' ng-if="transaction.confirmations < 6 || transaction.confirmations == null">unconfirmed</td>
                  <td class='green' ng-if="transaction.confirmations >= 6">confirmed</td>
                  <!-- <td>{{transaction.date}}</td> -->
                  <td><timer end-time="{{transaction.date}}">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer><td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The transaction.date is from a different controller than the directive and is a String formatted date in milliseconds.  You can also look here for examples of the directive. http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/

I am getting an error for using transaction.date in the timer directive.

Comment: But where's the question?

Comment: What is the error description?

Comment: The error is just a syntax error the question is more general and I'm just trying to show what I am trying to do. Which is grab the date from the backend and place it into the directive attribute end-time for each transaction.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears the main issue is communicating between controllers.

This is more of a structural issue and goes back to how you fundamentally decide to organize your application.

One of the big go-tos for communicating between controllers is to consolidate all of your data in a service or factory (Google for the documentation in the Angular API if you are unfamiliar with what a service is).

You keep all your relevant data in one little package (the service or factory), which can draw data from multiple sources. Then, in your controller, you simply pass in the service as an argument, and create a new instance of the service in your controller.

You might also consider using broadcast or emit functions (see the Angular API) which literally broadcast data globally either up or down the node tree, and your controllers can "grab" the data and use it, independent of the source.